# AWS S3 SDK - how do I set thread pool size?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I'm trying to set thread pool size for S3 multipart uploads to control number of parallel uploads being made.

As per this AWS blog page - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/parallelizing-large-uploads-for-speed-and-reliability/ I need to pass `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n)` to `TransferManager` but I cannot find a way to do the same with `TransferManagerBuilder`.

We have `TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withExecutorFactory()` that accepts `ExecutyorFactory` but it has no implementation.

How can I specify thread pool size using `TransferManagerBuilder`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JavaDoc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManagerBuilder.html#withExecutorFactory-com.amazonaws.client.builder.ExecutorFactory-) and [GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManagerBuilder.java#L148) suggest that there is a method `TransferManagerBuilder#withExecutorFactory` that takes an `ExecutorFactory`, with an implementation that sets it on the builder.

Make sure you call the `build` method on the builder, which should return you an instance of `TransferManager`.

```
final TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder
        .standard()
        .withExecutorFactory(() -> Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads))
        .build();
```

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` could be assigned to function accepting `ExecutorFactory`. Thanks!

Comment: Looking more closely at the interfaces, I was originally incorrect.  The `ExecutorFactory` is a functional interface, which will require a lambda wrapper to be correct.

Comment: Yes, it needed the wrapper. Although I don't quite understand how lambda expression is working here. Is it automatically creating a new implementation of `ExecutorFactory`?

Comment: The Lambda fulfills the functional interface of `ExecutorFactory`, which is a single abstract method (SAM) object.  The Lambda takes in no parameters, and returns an `ExecutorService`, which is effectively the same signature of ExecutorFactory.  It's a language feature of Java 8.